# Cause of Python type error 'unbound method'?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, class, methods

I am very new to Python , sorry for if I am a nuisance but I keep receiving this error whenever I try my code the error is as follows :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    fopen.open_file()
TypeError:<br> unbound method open_file() must be called with openFile instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

The aim of the program is to read in the file that the user inputs.

Here is my code:

```
class openFile:
    def file_to_open():
        fopen = raw_input('Enter the file path : ')
        open_file = open(fopen)
        print open_file
```

Comment: Why are you using a class?

Comment: The exception raised doesn't correspond to your code.

Comment: How did u use that class to create your instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to define file_to_open as a member function of the class openFile, right? If so, then you should get "self" as an argument:

```
def file_to_open(self):
 ...
```

and you should call it as follows:

```
f = openFile()
f.file_to_open()
```

---

That said, I think you should reconsider the use of a class here. Instead, you could just define a function

```
def open_a_file():
  filename = raw_input('Enter the file path : ')
  return open(filename)
```